# What is the difference between null and System.DBNull.Value?

Tags: c#, null, dbnull

Is there any difference between null and System.DBNull.Value? If yes, what is it?

I noticed this behavior now -

```
while (rdr.Read())
{
    if (rdr["Id"] != null) //if (rdr["Id"] != System.DBNull.Value)  
    {
        int x = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["Id"]);
    }
}
```

While I retrieve data from the database using a sql datareader, though there is no value returned `if(rdr["Id"] != null)` returned `true` and eventually threw an exception for casting a null as integer.

But, this if I use `if (rdr["Id"] != System.DBNull.Value)` returns `false`.

What's the difference between null and System.DBNull.Value?

Comment: Well, they're unrelated.  One is a static instance of a class in `System.Data`, and the other is a special value signifying the lack of a referent.  They have nothing to do with each other.  Can you elaborate on what you're confused about?  Is your real question "why do `DataRows` and `DataReaders` put `DBNull.Value` inside of themselves instead of `null`?"

Comment: Well, my it wasn't initially but after learning from what you said, I am curious. Could you tell me why DataRows and DataReaders put DBNull.Value in themselves instead of null?

Comment: I'm not sure myself.  Here's one answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488727/what-is-the-point-of-dbnull/4488758#4488758 It's also possible that before nullable value types were around in C#, it would have been more of a hassle to deal with `null`.

Comment: I had an answer here, but I realised it was more suitable for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488727/what-is-the-point-of-dbnull/ - so I moved it

Answer (score 133, accepted):

Well, `null` is not an instance of any type. Rather, it is an invalid reference.

However, `System.DbNull.Value`, is a valid reference to an instance of `System.DbNull` (`System.DbNull` is a singleton and `System.DbNull.Value` gives you a reference to the single instance of that class) that represents nonexistent<sup>*</sup> values in the database.

<sup>*We would normally say `null`, but I don't want to confound the issue.</sup>

So, there's a big conceptual difference between the two. The keyword `null` represents an invalid reference. The class `System.DbNull` represents a nonexistent value in a database field. In general, we should try avoid using the same thing (in this case `null`) to represent two very different concepts (in this case an invalid reference versus a nonexistent value in a database field).

Keep in mind, this is why a lot of people advocate using the [null object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) in general, which is exactly what `System.DbNull` is an example of.

Comment: +1 A practical example: if you use `IDbCommand.ExecuteScalar()`, it can either return null (no records returned) or `DbNull` (first column in first record is a 'nonexistent value'). Without `DbNull` you would not be able to distinguish one from the other.

Comment: I would strongly recommend to use a language which forbids the use of Null, and does so at absolutely 0 extra cost. life is too short for "null object pattern"

Comment: A null reference is perfectly valid. ☺

Comment: @C.Evenhuis Well, there is another common advice: a function should return only one type of value. That is why people prefer well-typed TypeScript code. "What is the status of the execution" differs from "What is the computational result". Ie. they could have decided to implement this function somehow else (maybe an out parameter, or an object similar to HTTP request response objs). Sure, this is a not-really wanted complication, but if they had done that, maybe null could be used instead of DbNull.

Answer (score 23):

From the documentation of the [DBNull class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/934efkk6.aspx):

> Do not confuse the notion of null in an object-oriented programming language with a DBNull object. In an object-oriented programming language, null means the absence of a reference to an object. DBNull represents an uninitialized variant or nonexistent database column.

Answer (score 12):

DBNull.Value is annoying to have to deal with.

I use static methods that check if it's DBNull and then return the value.

```
SqlDataReader r = ...;
String firstName = getString(r[COL_Firstname]);

private static String getString(Object o) {
   if (o == DBNull.Value) return null;
   return (String) o;
}
```

Also, when inserting values into a DataRow, you can't use "null", you have to use DBNull.Value.

Have two representations of "null" is a bad design for no apparent benefit.

Comment: The sentiment of disgust we share re: your last statement is trumped only by the irony of showing up here to read this and finding out your username is "loathing"

Answer (score 5):

DBNull.Value is what the .NET Database providers return to represent a null entry in the database.  DBNull.Value is not null and comparissons to null for column values retrieved from a database row will not work, you should always compare to DBNull.Value.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value.aspx

Comment: p.s.  You should also use DBNull.Value to pass a null parameter to the database, otherwise it may be interpretted as the parameter was not passed.

Comment: DBNull is *not* "what the database returns" - it is simply how ADO.NET chooses to interpret it; personally I'm not sure that this interpretation is very valuable

Comment: @MarcGravell Yes, Marc, you are correct.  I worded that incorrectly.  ASP.NET translates the database null column value into DBNull.Value

Answer (score 4):

DataRow has a method that is called `IsNull()` that you can use to test the column if it has a null value - regarding to the null as it's seen by the database.

`DataRow["col"]==null` will allways be `false`.

use

```
DataRow r;
if (r.IsNull("col")) ...
```

instead.

Answer (score 3):

Null is similar to **zero pointer in C++**. So it is a *reference which not pointing to any value*.

`DBNull.Value` is completely different and is a **constant** which is returned when a field value contains NULL.