# Whats Best Convert.ToSting() or Just Concatenate with an Empty String?

Tags: c#

```
var item = "" + dr["someString"];
```

Or

```
var item = Convert.ToString(dr["somestring"]);
```

What are the performance implications of the above examples?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about:

```
var item = (string)dr["someString"] ?? "";
```

which avoids an unnecessary concatenation, an unnecessary virtual call, and avoids the risk of calling a method on a null reference. It isn't clear what `dr` is in this context; if it is a data-reader (`IDataReader` etc) you might need:

```
int index = dr.GetOrdinal("someString");
var item = dr.IsDBNull(index) ? "" : dr.GetString(index);
```

or in the case of a `DataTable`, something involving `DataRow.IsNull`.

Comment: In this example its a DataRow

Comment: @Leigh of course, I'm not a fan of `DBNull` in the first place, but in the context of a `DataRow` you *could* use `dr.IsNull(...)`. It won't change the answer, but [some related notes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958379/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-system-dbnull-value/9632050#9632050) that you might find interesting.

Comment: @Leigh as an aside, it also shows the importance of including all relevant context in a question; in this case, it **really matters** what `dr` is defined as, so it would be useful to volunteer that in the question ;p

Comment: Cool so I can conclude that casting the object to a sting and checking if its null will be better for performance than just concatenating the object with an empty string?

Comment: @LeighCiechanowski well, the concat involves extra unnecessary steps - however, in the case of DataRow it won't be `null`, but `DbNull`, which is more work

Comment: hmm yes the code doesn't seem as readable I have now got dr.IsNull("someString") ? "" :(string)dr["someString"] which seems a lot less readable compared to "" + dr["someString"] which I'm tempted to go with unless its going to be bad for performance... I'm not really worried about performance because this is not going to loop or anything I was just curious.

Answer (score 2):

Whats wrong with `dr["someString"].ValueOrEmpty()`?

As for your original question. The performance will not matter. I promise you that there are several other areas that can be optimized which gives a lot better performance gain.

Write the most readable code. And do not optimize until it's proven that you need to.

**Update:**

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string ValueOrEmpty(this object obj)
    {
        return obj == null ? "" : obj.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes or doing it that way which is best?

Comment: @Mark, If `dr` is a DataRow, wouldn't dr["someThing"] return DBNull instead of null?

Comment: @zmbq that depends entirely on what `dr` is, which is not clear in the question. I actually wondered if it was "data reader", and have illustrated something similar in my answer.