# Why does DBNull.Value not work here?

Tags: c#

```
EnumType = reader["EnumTypeId"] == DBNull.Value ? EnumType.None : (EnumType)(int)reader["EnumTypeId"];
```

I thought if `reader["EnumTypeId"]` is null, it should assign the `EnumType.None` value, but it is still trying to cast the null value to an int which is obviously causing an exception.

I tried the following and it did not work either:

```
EnumType = reader["EnumTypeId"] == null ? EnumType.None : (EnumType)(int)reader["EnumTypeId"];
```

Instead of using `Enums`, I went ahead and decided to use a nullable `int`, so now my code is slightly different, but it still does not work with `DBNull.Value`, `null`, or `GetOrdinal...`

```
intType= reader["intType"] == DBNull.Value ? null : (int?)reader["intType"];
```

Also, why do I have to do a `(int?)` cast instead of just a `(int)` cast?

Comment: try this one `reader["EnumTypeId"] == null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use DBNull, just use plain old `null`.

```
EnumType = reader["EnumTypeId"] == null ? EnumType.None : (EnumType)(int)reader["EnumTypeId"];
```

---

**Edit**

The issue could be that the database type of `EnumTypeId` isn't an int/Int32.  If so, then reading as a string and then parsing should fix the problem.

```
EnumType? enumVal = null;
if (reader["EnumTypeId"] != null)
{
    int intVal;
    enumVal = (int.TryParse(reader["EnumTypeId"].ToString(), out intVal)) ? (EnumType)intVal : null;
}
EnumType =  ? EnumType.None : (EnumType)(int)reader["EnumTypeId"];
```

Comment: What is the difference between DBNull and null?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958379/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-system-dbnull-value

Comment: I can't see a straight answer in the documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx), but I remember that using `null` "works".  Maybe Cuong Le's answer is more correct, I really don't know.

Comment: I decided to try just using an int instead of an enum, but still getting errors.  Take a look at my updated post.

Comment: It was totally something else, both DBNull.Value and null work, I just forgot to add the column to the stored proc that brings back the data.  It totally slipped my mind.

Answer (score 1):

Another way you can use is `IsDBNull` method:

```
int index = reader.GetOrdinal("EnumTypeId");
EnumType = reader.IsDBNull(index) ? EnumType.None : 
                                    (EnumType)reader.GetInt32(index);
```

Comment: Is it possible to bypass the GetOrdinal and get the above into one statement?

Comment: @Xaisoft: With GetOrdinal you can use IsDBNull and GetInt32, I found this clearer

Comment: Tried this as well and it did not work.  I have updated my code so I will update my post