# Should I check for null or dbnull in the query

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have a query which checks how many records of a certain type are there using `count()`.

```
select count(*) from abc where date="some value"
```

Here, is it possible that my query returns `null` or `DBNull`? Should I check for them?

Comment: A wise person once said, "an experiment is worth a thousand expert opinions."  Try it out, try `where date="some value you know is not present"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try it:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE 1=2
--Returns 0
```

Per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

> COUNT always returns an **int** data type value.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think so: it can return zero or greater, since you're counting.

`NULL` would be a wrong result, since *no results* is *there're zero results*.

Answer (score 3):

No, it will always return a number greater or equal to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ExecuteScalar, I think the call will retrieve null instead of a DbNull object.

What I use to do in order to always receive a value is encapsulating my request:
SELECT ISNULL((SELECT COUNT(date) FROM abc WHERE date = "some value"), 0)

Serge

Comment: I can't understand which is the case where you'll get `null` when you're counting.

Comment: `count(*)` is always >= 0 and never `DBNull` or `null`. This query will always return one row!

Answer (score 0):

You should check `DbNull` as it is database oriented.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958379/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-system-dbnull-value)

Answer (score 0):

This is what i do:

```
if (rdr.HasRows)
        {
          rdr.Read();
          if (rdr["MyField"] != DBNull.Value)
                {
                   bla bla....
                }
```

So yes check for DBNull.