# DBNull error is coming up

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a database table as

```
FruitCrateTable FruitCrateID, FruitCrateName, FruitGarden
```

Now I also created a Stored procedure as,

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[GetFruitCrate]
(
    @FruitCrateID int,
    @FruitCrateName varchar(222)
)
AS

SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    FruitCrateTable
WHERE
    FruitCrateID = @FruitCrateID
and
    FruitCrateName = @FruitCrateName
```

Now when I try to check if FruitGarden is null or not using DataAccess,

I created instance of row as,

```
 public myDataAccess.DataAccess.GetFruitCrateRow fruitCrateRow;
 //then

 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fruitCrateRow.FruitGarden))
            {
//do something but i am getting error, how can i fix this issue ?
else { // do something else }
```

Error,

```
The value for column &#39;FruitGarden&#39; in table &#39;GetFruitCrate&#39; is DBNull.</message><full>System.Data.StrongTypingException: The value for column &#39;FruitGarden&#39; in table &#39;GetFruitCrate&#39; is DBNull. ---&gt; System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type &#39;System.DBNull&#39; to type &#39;System.String&#39;.
```

***I left Fruit Garden as Null as it can be null***

**Update**

when i try fruitCrateRow.FruitGarden != DBNull.Value I get Error     Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'System.DBNull

Comment: Your stored proc is `[dbo].[GetFruitCrate]`, but you're calling `GetFruitCrateRow`?

Comment: @PatLillis I renamed my scenario

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`DBNull`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.aspx) is not the same as `null`. Try with

```
if (!DBNull.Value.Equals(fruitCrateRow.FruitGarden) && 
     fruitCrateRow.FruitGarden != "")
```

Answer (score 6):

Well, as stated by the Exception, `fuitCraterow.FruitGarden` is `DBNull`, which can't be casted to a string (which happens when you call `string.IsNullOrEmpty`)

So... test for `DbNull`

```
if (!DBNull.Value.Equals(fruitCrateRow.FruitGarden) && 
   !string.IsNullOrEmpty(fruitCraterow.FruitGarden))
```

to check for DbNull, see [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value.aspx)

> To evaluate database fields to determine whether their values are
>   DBNull, you can pass the field value to the DBNull.Value.Equals
>   method. However, this method is rarely used because there are a number
>   of other ways to evaluate a database field for missing data. These
>   include the Visual Basic IsDBNull function, the Convert.IsDBNull
>   method, the DataTableReader.IsDBNull method, the IDataRecord.IsDBNull
>   method, and several other methods.

So

```
if (!Convert.IsDBNull(fruitCrateRow.FruitGarden) && 
     !string.IsNullOrEmpty(fruitCrateRow.FruitGarden)
```

should also be fine.

**EDIT**

you can still add your `string.IsNullOrEmpty` test after the DBNull test, as it will be evaluated only if left part is true.

Comment: when i try fruitCrateRow.FruitGarden != DBNull.Value  I get Error  Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'System.DBNull

Comment: @user13814 you're right, corrected and edited (but Claudio Redi had already corrected)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than `string.isNullOrEmpty` you'll need to check:

```
if (fruitCrateRow.FruitGarden != DbNull.Value)
            {
//do something but i am getting error, how can i fix this issue ?
```

As it's a Database null.

See:
[What is the difference between null and System.DBNull.Value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958379/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-system-dbnull-value)

and:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.aspx