# RowFilter of DataView for DBNull values of object type

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable, null, dbnull

How would the filter string looks like for DBNull values in DataTable.

```
"IsNull("Column1", 'Null Column')='Null Column'"
"IsNull("Column1", 'Null Column')<>'Null Column'"
```

This string to filter Null values in the Column1. It works fine if it is a String column and throws exception for other types.

Any idea on this?

And also i want to know whether Null and DBNull for object type of column is same?
[image]

```
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Title", typeof (string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("TitleID", typeof(Int32)) {AllowDBNull = true});
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Date", typeof(object)) );
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Desc", typeof(string)));

        for(int i =0; i<10; i++)
        {
            var input = i%2 == 0 ? (object) i : DBNull.Value;
            var result = input.Equals(DBNull.Value);

            DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
            row["Title"] = "C#" + i;
            row["TitleID"] = i % 2 == 0 ? (object) i : DBNull.Value;
            row["Date"] = i == 2 ? (object) DateTime.Now : DBNull.Value;
            row["Desc"] = i % 2 == 0 ? null : ""; 
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        DataView defView = dt.DefaultView;

        defView.RowFilter = "IsNull(Date, 'Null Column')='Null Column'";

        var filtered = defView;
```

Comment: Have you checked my answer below ?

Comment: what is the datatype of `P4` ?

Comment: P4 is `typeof(object)` but am inserting values of `DateTime`. Is it any problem with this?

Comment: `P4` should be the name of the column of your `DataTable` which is coming from database.

Comment: @Arshad: Yes, `P4` is the name of column which is coming from database.

Comment: what is the data-type ?

Comment: I have defined the column as type of object and assigning some `DateTime`, `DBNull.Value`(s). In this case, column type is considered as type of DateTime and it is compared with Null. But i dono exactly what the problem is.

Comment: are you defining a `DataTable` and filling up, or you are using `DataAdapter` to fill the `DataTable` ?

Comment: share your code, so that we can help you out ?

Comment: @Arshad: Added my code..

Comment: Check the updated part

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
 dataView.RowFilter = "JoinDate IS null";
```

Answer (score 0):

I am filtering the `DataTable` based on `NULL` Email ID :

```
  var results = from DataRow myRow in dtCustomer.Rows
                          where (object)myRow["EmailID"] == DBNull.Value
                          select myRow;
            DataTable dt = results.CopyToDataTable();
```

And there is a good explanation about `NULL` and `DBNULL`  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958379/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-system-dbnull-value).

As per the [msdn remarks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter.aspx):

```
   // DataTable dtCst = dtCustomer.Select("Isnull(EmailID,'Null Column') =
                                           'Null Column'").CopyToDataTable();
  //or
        DataView dataView = dtCustomer.DefaultView;
        dataView.RowFilter = "Isnull(EmailID,'Null Column') = 'Null Column'";
```

I have also tested with `JoinDate` which is `NULL` in DB and datatype is `datetime` and also tested with `date` type.

```
   dataView.RowFilter = "Isnull(JoinDate,'Null Column') = 'Null Column'";
```

### Updated

Update your code :

```
 dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Date", typeof(DateTime)) { AllowDBNull = true });
```

in your `for loop` :

```
if (i == 2)
   {
      row["Date"] = DateTime.Now;
   }
```

then filter. it will work.

Comment: Might be but am using DataView of DataTable, so am using its RowFilter which accepts string. That's why am looking for Filter string. How do i?

Comment: You can use LINQ without any issue

Comment: Yes but i was limited to RowFilter only.. That's why am asking for the filter string.

Comment: Yes, This is the code where i given in my query. This works fine for String column but throws exception for other type columns. please ave a look on the attached image..

Comment: For the defined Data types, it will works am asking about the object type and casting a type (like DateTime) to object. In this case its not working..

Comment: Am really thank full to you for spending ur valuable time to solve my problem.. Since it is type of object, any type of values can be added to that column in runtime. This need to filtered with DBNull.Value. This is my requirement..