# Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.Byte[]'

Tags: c#

I have this code :

```
UploadImageControl1.BinaryData =ServiceInfoDt["SERVICE_LOGO"]!=null?(byte []) ServiceInfoDt["SERVICE_LOGO"]:null;
```

`BinaryData` is a byte array `byte[]`

buy i am receiving this error :

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.Byte[]'.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should check with [**System.DBNull.Value**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of `null`

> If a database field has missing data, you can use the DBNull.Value property to explicitly assign a DBNull object value to the field. However, most data providers do this automatically.

Thus use

```
UploadImageControl1.BinaryData = 
    ServiceInfoDt["SERVICE_LOGO"]!= System.DBNull.Value 
    ? (byte []) ServiceInfoDt["SERVICE_LOGO"]
    : null;
```

Read [What is the difference between null and System.DBNull.Value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958379/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-system-dbnull-value)