# DBNull check for ExecuteScalar

Tags: c#, sql, dbnull

The stored procedure for command can return null.Is it correct way to check if the returned value is null or should I also check that obj is null?

```
object obj = command.ExecuteScalar();
int id = -1;
if (DBNull.Value == obj)
{
   id = Convert.ToInt32(obj );
}
```

Comment: Execute scalar will always return a generic object. Hence it would be better to check for null before checking for the object value.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You probably want to change your if-statement to

```
if (obj != null && DBNull.Value != obj) { 
    ... 
}
```

Right now you're trying to convert if `obj == DBNull.Value`.

Answer (score 5):

If there is no result your query can return `null`, so in the general case you should check for it.  E.g.:

```
SELECT TOP 1 Col1 FROM TABLE WHERE ...
```

The above query can return:

- `null` if there are no rows matching the WHERE clause
- `DBNull.Value` if the first matching row has a NULL value in Col1
- else a non-null value

If your query is such that you can guarantee there will always be a result, you only need to check for DBNull.  E.g.

```
SELECT MAX(Col1) FROM TABLE WHERE ...
```

The above query will return DBNull.Value if there are no rows matching the WHERE clause.  It never returns `null`.

And of course there are some cases where you can guarantee a non-null result, in which case you don't need to test for null or DBNull.  E.g.

```
SELECT COUNT(Col1) FROM TABLE WHERE ...
SELECT ISNULL(MAX(Col1),0) FROM TABLE WHERE ...
```

The above query will always return a non-null value.  It never returns `null` or `DBNull.Value`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `System.DBNull.Value`. check this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Try this :

```
if(DBNull.Value != obj)
{
 ....
 .... 
}
```

Here is difference between `Null` and `DBNull`. [What is the difference between null and System.DBNull.Value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958379/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-system-dbnull-value)