# PowerShell Tab Separated File Import and Blank Values

Tags: powershell

I have recently changed my script to import data from a csv file to a tab separated file. The issue that I am having is when there is a blank value in the tab separated file in say $var1 it does not treat $var as either NULL or "", I was thinking there is a tab stored in the variable, so I striped the variabled from containing tabs, the same issue still occurring. The tab separated file contains 6 columns and 5 rows and the headers are added when the file is imported using the below command.

My question is what will be read from a tab separated file if one of the columns is blank?

```
        The command used to import the files contents.
        $List = Import-Csv C:\Users\jsmith\Documents\file.out -Delimiter "`t" -Header "ID","Date","First Name","Last Name","Gender"
```

Comment: I was unable to reproduce your bug.  When I tried it with sample data, the missing value was an empty string:

    1 \t 6/10/2014 \t John \t Doe \t M \t X
    2 \t 6/01/2014 \t Frank \t O'Connor \t M \t X
    3 \t 4/10/2012 \t Fred \t  \t M \t X

$List[2].'Last Name'.GetType() returned System.String, and
$List[2].'Last Name'.Length returned 0

Comment: I am receiving different results for different variables. When $var.length for one variable it returns as 0. When $var1.length for another I dont receive anything back. When I $var.gettype() it displays as a string however when I $var1.gettype() I receive the error 'You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.' Both the variables are empty after importing from the tab separated file.

Comment: I have broken it down as shown below, I have used different header names from my original post;

$List = Import-Csv C:\Users\jsmith\Documents\file.out -Delimiter "`t" -Header "ID","Date","First Name","Mid. Name","postOfficeBox"
ForEach ($record in $List) {
$middleName_file_value = $record."Mid. Name"
 $middleName_file_value
 $POBox_file_value = $record.postOfficeBox
 $POBox_file_value
 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try evaluating for `[System.DBNull]::Value`.

I typically assign it to a variable to make it easy to evaluate later:

```
$DBnull = [System.DBNull]::Value
if ($value -eq $DBNull) {
    # Do stuff
    }
```

Comment: Evaluating for [System.DBNull]::Value is answer, I was originally evaluating for $NULL and didn't resolve the issue however [System.DBNull]::Value does :) What is the difference between the two.

Comment: This may help explain it a little bit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958379/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-system-dbnull-value

Comment: Thank you for the information, this has answered my question.