# System.DBNull Error on formatting DataGridView C#

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I'm new to C# so I have been following some guides and adapting it to fit my application. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellformattingeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx) is one of the ones I followed from Microsoft.

I have used the same code as what they have suggested and I get an error.

[image]

My code simply looks at the data in the DataGridView and highlights the line with red if the condition is met.
This is my code:

```
        private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {

        //Set the row definition
        DataGridViewRow row = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        //If we are on the validating column
        if (this.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "SelectedUID")
        {
            //check criteria
            string stringValue = (string)e.Value;
            if ((stringValue.IndexOf("JL") > -1))
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("The Format Value " + e.Value);
                //format the row colour
                row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
                row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("The Value " + e.Value);
            }
        }

    }
```

What is it that I have got wrong with the conversion of the object? I have tried many other solutions. Additional to this I tried to test:

```
if (e.value != null)
```

but this did not even read a null value in there so I'm not sure what was being returned because I checked the length and it was 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DBNull.Value` is of type `DBNull` and cannot be cast to a `string`. Instead, use `Convert.ToString` to handle this case.

[Demo](http://rextester.com/DDVO56271)

Also, for what it's worth, `DBNull.Value` is not the same as `null`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958379/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-system-dbnull-value) for details.

Comment: Sorry would you mind giving me an example: e.Value.convert.ToString?

Comment: Also this is the code they give in the Microsoft Tutorial - I'm not sure why they would teach us the wrong things :(

Comment: No idea, but if you read the MSDN page on DBNull.Value, you will see their example doing an explicit check to see if the value returned is equal to DBNull.Value before processing it further. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: No worries. Also, something to keep in mind - try doing explicit checks for DBNull when handling data retrieved from DB.

Comment: Just one more question - once i've converted to string it can only be Null and no more other types of nulls right? So I can have  - if(stringValue != null)

Comment: Well, `Convert.ToString()` will return `String.Empty` in this case. But yes, once you have assigned the result to a string, you can check *that* string against the usual `null`.

Answer (score 0):

The value of this field in the database is NULL, you can't cast DBNull to a string. Try:

```
string stringValue = e.Value as string;
```

... if cou want the `stringValue` to be null, when the database value is DBNull, or:

```
string stringValue = e.Value == DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : (string)e.Value;
```

... if you want the `stringValue` to be empty (""), when the database value is DBNull.

Answer (score 0):

First check if the value is DBNull:

```
        if (Convert.IsDBNull(e.Value) {

        } else {
           string stringValue = (string)e.Value;
           if ((stringValue.IndexOf("JL") > -1))
           {
               Debug.WriteLine("The Format Value " + e.Value);
               //format the row colour
               row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
               row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
           }
           else
           {
              Debug.WriteLine("The Value " + e.Value);
           }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this : `string stringValue  =Convert.ToString(e.Value);`

or you can use `Nullable`  keyword in datatype.