# check the dataset for null values

Tags: c#

i want to check all my data set for null values and replace them.
in order to do it i wrote this code:

```
public static DataSet Validator(DataSet dataSet)
{
    foreach (DataTable dataTable in dataSet.Tables)
    foreach (DataRow dataRow in dataTable.Rows)
    foreach (DataColumn dataDataColumn in dataTable.Columns)
    if (dataRow[dataDataColumn] == DBNull.Value)
    {
        if (dataRow[dataDataColumn].GetType() == typeof(string)) 
            dataRow[dataDataColumn] = "";
        else if (dataRow[dataDataColumn].GetType() == typeof(DateTime))
            dataRow[dataDataColumn] = DateTime.MinValue;
        else if (dataRow[dataDataColumn].GetType() == typeof(int) ||
                 dataRow[dataDataColumn].GetType() == typeof(short) ||
                 dataRow[dataDataColumn].GetType() == typeof(long) ||
                 dataRow[dataDataColumn].GetType() == typeof(float) ||
                 dataRow[dataDataColumn].GetType() == typeof(byte) ||
                 dataRow[dataDataColumn].GetType() == typeof(double)) 
            dataRow[dataDataColumn] = 0;
    }

    return dataSet;
}
```

but it doesn't work!. where is the problem?
and if there is a better way i really appreciated to let me know.
Thank you.

**UPDATE**
but it doesn't work!. still there is null values in the dataset.

Comment: What does not work? Are there any exceptions?

Comment: "It doesn't work" isn't a helpful error report. Does it not compile? Does it throw an exception when you run it? Does it leave nulls? Does it set things to `42` instead of the value you want? Give more details and you are more likely to get help.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: I'm not sure, but if `dataRow[dataDataColumn]` is `null`, then `GetType` will be also `null`... like I said, I'm not sure. Test it just to see, for example `MessageBox.Show(dataRow[dataDataColumn].GetType.ToString());`... if that is true, You get `null`, so there none of condition is satisfied and nothing will be stored into field, operation will be skipped. And, I think, after `foreach (DataRow dataRow in dataTable.Rows)` You have to put one more code `dataTable.AcceptChanges();`... even for `dataSet`, too.

Comment: How about simply changing the columns in the data table to not allow null values specifying the desired default value?

Comment: @nelek If `dataRow[dataDataColumn]` would be `null`, `GetType()` would throw a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: It is a poor naming `Validator` when it actually doing value replacing job

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run

```
dataRow[dataDataColumn].GetType()
```

you call `GetType()` on the value of `dataRow[dataDataColumn]`, which is always `DBNull.value`. So you always get the type `DBNull`.

Check for `dataDataColumn.DataType` instead, which will return the actual datatype of the column.

---

You could use something like:

```
public static DataSet Validator(DataSet dataSet)
{
    foreach (DataTable dataTable in dataSet.Tables)
        foreach (DataRow dataRow in dataTable.Rows)
            foreach (DataColumn dataDataColumn in dataTable.Columns)
                if (dataRow.IsNull(dataDataColumn))
                    dataRow[dataDataColumn] = GetDefaultValue(dataDataColumn.DataType);

    return dataSet;
}

static object GetDefaultValue(Type t)
{
    // get the default value for value types
    if (t.IsValueType)
        return Activator.CreateInstance(t);

    // in case of a string, we want an empty one instead of null
    if (t == typeof(string))
        return String.Empty;

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using DBNull.Value to check for null values, try testing it against Null as well.

There is a difference between DBNull.Value and Null as previously explained here [What is the difference between null and System.DBNull.Value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958379/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-system-dbnull-value)

Comment: That's not the problem. A `null` value is represented by `DBNull.Value` in a `DataTable`.