# String.IsNullOrEmpty VS IsDBNull in validation when using IIF and IF ELSE

Tags: sql, vb.net, if-statement, null, iif

This is not clear to me, so if anyone can explain in detailed if what is the difference of the two functions (**IsDBNull** and **String.IsNullOrEmpty**) of VB.Net.

Below is my scenario why i ask that, i have column `Company` in my table which the value is `NULL`, then i used `IIF` function of vb.net to validate if it is `NULL` then assign empty string (""), else assign the value coming from data table

**Scenario:**

1. Below is using **String.IsNullOrEmpty** and i get a conversion error:

   > *Conversion from type 'DBNULL' to 'String' is not valid.*

   ```
   txtCompany.Text = IIf(String.IsNullOrEmpty(dtSample.Rows(grdInfo.SelectedIndex).Item("Company")).ToString, "", dtSample.Rows(grdInfo.SelectedIndex).Item("Company"))
   ```
2. However when i replace String.IsNullOrEmpty by **IsDBNull** , the validation works fine.

   ```
   txtCompany.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(dtSample.Rows(grdInfo.SelectedIndex).Item("Company")).ToString, "", dtSample.Rows(grdInfo.SelectedIndex).Item("Company"))
   ```

**EDIT:**

And it is confusing because if i did the validation using `IF ELSE` condition (see sample code below) with the use of String.IsNullOrEmpty, it works fine.

```
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(dtSample.Rows(grdInfo.SelectedIndex).Item("Company").ToString) = True Then
        txtCompany.Text = ""
    Else
        txtCompany.Text = dtSample.Rows(grdInfo.SelectedIndex).Item("Company").ToString
    End If
```

The confusing part is when i used `IIF(String.IsNullOrEmpty...etc)` it returns an error. but when i used the normal `IF String.IsNullOrEmpty(dtSample.Rows....etc) = True` it works fine.

Any explanation would much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958379/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-system-dbnull-value

Comment: @NoAlias i saw that, but that is `NULL` , system.dbnull.. what's not clear to me is the difference of String.IsNullOrEmpty and IsDBNull base on my given scenario above.

Comment: This question is a result of having the strict compiler option set to off, a novice's choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot mix and match `String.IsNullOrEmpty` and `IsDBNull` because they work on two different things.  The first on strings, the second on Data items read from the database.

But a very important element of this is that your code is invalid.  Neither "Scenario" snippet compiles under `Option Strict`.  If you leave VB to guess what you mean, you will get confusing results.

Snippet 1:

```vb
txtCompany.Text = IIf(String.IsNullOrEmpty(dtSample.Rows(grdInfo.SelectedIndex).Item("Company")).ToString, "", dtSample.Rows(grdInfo.SelectedIndex).Item("Company"))
```

Simplified:

```vb
Dim foo = IIf(String.IsNullOrEmpty(zDT.Rows(23).Item("Name")).ToString,
                "", zDT.Rows(23).Item("Name"))
```

This is illegal because `zDT.Rows(23).Item("Name")` is an object, but `String.IsNullOrEmpty` expects a string. Your `ToString` is misplaced - it is not converting the db Item, it is converting the entire `IIF` bool expresion!

The compiler warns you of both with`Option Strict On`.

The conversion throws an exception because VB must convert the db `Object` item ( `zDT.Rows(23).Item("Name")`) to a string.  The way it does it results in an error when when the db data is DBNull.

Snippet 2:

```vb
txtCompany.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(dtSample.Rows(grdInfo.SelectedIndex).Item("Company")).ToString, "", dtSample.Rows(grdInfo.SelectedIndex).Item("Company"))
```

Simplified:

```vb
foo = IIf(IsDBNull(zDT.Rows(23).Item("Name")).ToString, 
               "", zDT.Rows(23).Item("Name"))
```

This is slightly better but a string is till being used in place of the Boolean expression.  When fixed, you have:

```vb
IsDBNull(zDT.Rows(23).Item("Name"))
```

IsDBNull is testing a database item (Object) to see if it has data.  It will work.  `IsNullOrEmpty` should not be used to test for DBNull and cant with `Option Strict`.  You'd have to convert the dbItem to string first, then it will only work depending on how you convert.

```vb
' cant use string method to test an object
String.IsNullOrEmpty(zDT.Rows(23).Item("Name"))

' this will work:
String.IsNullOrEmpty(zDT.Rows(23).Item("Name").ToString)

' this will not:
String.IsNullOrEmpty(CStr(zDT.Rows(23).Item("Name")))
```

Use DBNull tests for data objects, and `IsNullOrEmpty` on strings.

Also, if you use the newer `If` operator in place of the old `IIf` function you can avoid other issues.  The operator allows short circuiting, the syntax is the same:

```vb
Dim foo = If(bool expr, True result, False result)
```

Comment: Finally! there is someone understand me very well base on my given example :) Thank you very much @Plutonix , Now i understand what differs to the two functions and what i've done wrong in my code, i tried this one `String.IsNullOrEmpty(zDT.Rows(23).Item("Name").ToString)` and it works , thats means i recieve an error before because of the wrong conversion of object to string using `String.IsNullOrEmpty`, but right conversion when i used `IsDBNull`, you have explained it very clear with simplifying my sample. Thanks you very much. :)

Comment: This is the best explanation as it understand my sample code very well and you have explained the whole thing, accepting this as answer. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 5):

**TL;DR**

- `String.IsNullOrEmpty()` checks only for Empty (`[blank]` i.e. `''` or `""`) or `Null` values it does **not** check `DBNull`, if any field coming from database has its value DBNull it will raise an error.
- `IsDBNull()` checks for `DBNull` (it is not same as `Null`)
- **`.ToString` will convert `DBNull` to Empty String i.e. `''`**

**Details**
Consider following SQL table example (using SQL Server as base)

Table Structure:

```
Column_Name        Type and Size   Other Properties
----------------   -------------   ----------------------
Company_ID         int             IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
Company_Name       nvarchar (50)                 NOT NULL   
Company_Address    nvarchar (50)                     NULL
```

INSERT statements:

```
INSERT [tbl_company] ([Company_Name], [Company_Address]) VALUES ('ABC', 'QWERT')
INSERT [tbl_company] ([Company_Name], [Company_Address]) VALUES ('ASD', ' ')
INSERT [tbl_company] ([Company_Name], [Company_Address]) VALUES ('XYZ', '')
INSERT [tbl_company] ([Company_Name])                    VALUES ('PQR')
```

Table Data:

```
Company_ID    Company_Name      Company_Address
-----------   ----------------  ---------------
1             ABC               QWERT
2             ASD               [SPACE]
3             XYZ               [BLANK]
4             PQR               NULL
```

Testing Company_Address with IsNullOrEmpty() and IsDBNull() using a SqlDataReader (r):

```
Company_ID IsNullOrEmpty(r("Company_Address")) IsDBNull(r("Company_Address"))
---------- ----------------------------------- ------------------------------
1          False                               False
2          False                               False
3          True                                False
4          ERROR                               True
```

**And now specific to the Question**
What the OP is trying here, lets consider all statements one by one

The IIF statement with IsNullOrEmpty (**wrong**)

```
txtCompany.Text = IIf(String.IsNullOrEmpty(dtSample.Rows(grdInfo.SelectedIndex).Item("Company")).ToString, "", dtSample.Rows(grdInfo.SelectedIndex).Item("Company"))
```

In this statement OP is accessing the value as `dtSample.Rows(grdInfo.SelectedIndex).Item("Company")` and checking it with `IsNullOrEmpty()` and then converting the result of IsNullOrEmpty to string using `.ToString` i.e. `IsNullOrEmpty(value).ToString()`. If the value is DBNull it will always return an error. The correct way to use it is

```
IsNullOrEmpty(dtSample.Rows(grdInfo.SelectedIndex).Item("Company").ToString)
```

**See last part `Company")).ToString` vs `Company").ToString)`, just a case of MISPLACED ")"**

Second (IIF with IsDBNull) and third (IF with IsNullOrEmpty) statements of OP are correct

```
txtCompany.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(dtSample.Rows(grdInfo.SelectedIndex).Item("Company")).ToString, "", dtSample.Rows(grdInfo.SelectedIndex).Item("Company"))

If String.IsNullOrEmpty(dtSample.Rows(grdInfo.SelectedIndex).Item("Company").ToString) = True Then
    txtCompany.Text = ""
Else
    txtCompany.Text = dtSample.Rows(grdInfo.SelectedIndex).Item("Company").ToString
End If
```

As regards to the second statement OP is correctly ordering the parameters i.e. first `Company` field is converted to string using `dtSample.Rows(grdInfo.SelectedIndex).Item("Company").ToString`. This converts any DBNull to Empty string and then it checked for `IsNullOrEmpty`. Now as the value has already been converted to EmptyString it will not give any error.

**Old discussions with OP**

The difference is clear in your text. Your first statement is:

```
txtCompany.Text = IIf(String.IsNullOrEmpty(dtSample.Rows(grdInfo.SelectedIndex).Item("Company")).ToString, "", dtSpecifierRebate.Rows(grdInfo.SelectedIndex).Item("Company"))
```

and the second one is

```
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(dtSample.Rows(grdInfo.SelectedIndex).Item("Company").ToString) = True Then
```

Now break them apart, first statement **(IIF)**

```
String.IsNullOrEmpty(dtSample.Rows(grdInfo.SelectedIndex).Item("Company")).ToString
'Item("Company")).ToString
```

And second part **(IF)**

```
String.IsNullOrEmpty(dtSample.Rows(grdInfo.SelectedIndex).Item("Company").ToString)
'Item("Company").ToString)
```

Found any difference?
In first statement you are **converting the result of IsNullOrEmpty** to String
In second one you are **converting .Item("Company") ToString** and then comparing it.

**If `.Item("Company")` returns DBNull**
then IsNullOrEmpty failed because .Item("Company") returned type **DBNull** whereas IsNullOrEmpty checks for **null**
IsDBNull worked because it checks for **DBNull**

**All point of a misplaced bracket ")"** It's a typo

And regarding your usage of these statements:
If and IIF need to check the results as booleans and not as strings
It is better recommended to remove the ToString portion of your statements

Comment: Then where is the `IsDBNull` part of your answer ? , you focus on the `IF` condition only, `IIF` has 3 parameters that's why closing bracket did not place after .ToString since that is only first parameter, the closing bracket will be place after the 3rd parameter of `IIF`

Comment: It should have been like this `txtCompany.Text = IIf(String.IsNullOrEmpty(dtSample.Rows(grdInfo.SelectedIndex).Item("Company")), "", dtSpecifierRebate.Rows(grdInfo.SelectedIndex).Item("Company"))`
. IsNullOrEmpty will always fail if your database returns null (i.e. DBNull) for field Company and `txtCompany.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(dtSample.Rows(grdInfo.SelectedIndex).Item("Company")), "", dtSpecifierRebate.Rows(grdInfo.SelectedIndex).Item("Company"))`

Comment: Or better IsDBNull as `txtCompany.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(dtSample.Rows(grdInfo.SelectedIndex).Item("Company")), "", dtSpecifierRebate.Rows(grdInfo.SelectedIndex).Item("Company").ToString)`. (Add ToString in the last). I just noticed two different DTs in your statement dtSample and dtSpecifierRebate

Comment: As regards to your `IF` and `IIF` focus, it is because of their different structure in your statements **MISPLACED bracket ")"** (NOT missed) which I have already explained above

Comment: just ignore the dtSpecifierRebate, i modified the question to remove that, only dtSample , i am testing it now (removing .ToString) with the use of `String.IsNullOrEmpty` if it will work. , because using `IsDBNull` works on me, but i was wondering if why `String.IsNullOrEmpty` has a conversion error, i'll get back to after testing it. Thanks

Comment: And remember IsNullOrEmpty will always give conversion error if Company field in your database table is DBNull because value of type DBNull can not converted to string, its neither a space nor a blank. For a value coming from a database table you must always use IsDBNull to check for null values

Comment: removing .ToString didn't work, still return the same error message, the confusing part is in my EDIT on question above, when i used `IF ELSE` condition, it works fine even the value of my database is `NULL` , that is i wanted to know, but i am giving you +1 vote for the detailed answer.

Comment: Compare your `IIF` statement `String.IsNullOrEmpty(dtSample.Rows(grdInfo.SelectedIndex).Item("Company")).ToString` and `IF` statement `String.IsNullOrEmpty(dtSample.Rows(grdInfo.SelectedIndex).Item("Company").ToString)` Just check brackets `Company")).ToString` and `Company").ToString)`. The value is still `DBNull` in `Company")).ToString` and value has been converted to `EmptyString` in `Company").ToString)` before comparison

Comment: Excellent catch on "dtSample.Rows(grdInfo.SelectedIndex).Item("Company")).ToString"  and good explanation in general.

Answer (score 1):

The [IsNullOrEmpty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb) function checks whether or not a string is empty or null.  [DBNull](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull(v=vs.90).aspx) is not null (Nothing), but rather is a class that indicates a value from a database does not exist.  [IsDbNull](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tckcces5(v=vs.90).aspx) checks for whether or not a value equals DBNull.

You may not be getting the error you mention in the question on the line of code referenced as this runs just fine for me:

```
        strTest = IIf(String.IsNullOrEmpty(DBNull.Value.ToString), "", DBNull.Value)
```

Comment: it is still not clear to me, i tried to use `IF ELSE` with `String.IsNullOrEmpty` and it works fine. , see edited question above.

Comment: I've edited.  Are you sure you're getting the error on the line of code you mention in your question?

Comment: yup i am sure it returns an error, but when i replace `String.IsNullOrEmpty` by `IsDBNull` , then it works fine with `IIF` condition, but the confusing part is when i used the normal `IF ELSE` condition, the `String.IsNullOrEmpty` did not return an error. it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

IsDBNull Function :

Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether an expression evaluates to the System.DBNull class.

IsDBNull returns True if the data type of Expression evaluates to the DBNull type; otherwise, IsDBNull returns False.
The System.DBNull value indicates that the Object represents missing or nonexistent data. DBNull is not the same as Nothing, which indicates that a variable has not yet been initialized. DBNull is also not the same as a zero-length string (""), which is sometimes referred to as a null string.

example :

```
 Dim testVar As Object 
   Dim nullCheck As Boolean
      nullCheck = IsDBNull(testVar)
     testVar = ""
     nullCheck = IsDBNull(testVar)
     testVar = System.DBNull.Value
    nullCheck = IsDBNull(testVar)
     '  The first two calls to IsDBNull return False; the third returns True..
```

String.IsNullOrEmpty :

Indicates whether the specified string is null or an Empty string.
IsNullOrEmpty is a convenience method that enables you to simultaneously test whether a String is null or its value is Empty.

Example :

```
    Class Sample
   Public Shared Sub Main()
  Dim s1 As String = "abcd"
  Dim s2 As String = ""
  Dim s3 As String = Nothing

  Console.WriteLine("String s1 {0}.", Test(s1))
  Console.WriteLine("String s2 {0}.", Test(s2))
  Console.WriteLine("String s3 {0}.", Test(s3))
   End Sub

   Public Shared Function Test(s As String) As String
     If String.IsNullOrEmpty(s) Then
     Return "is null or empty"
    Else
     Return String.Format("(""{0}"") is neither null nor empty", s)
    End If
   End Function 
 End Class  
     'The example displays the following output:
    'String s1 ("abcd") is neither null nor empty.
     'String s2 is null or empty.
      'String s3 is null or empty.
```

Comment: thanks but i am still confuse, because when i used the `IF ELSE` using `String.IsNullOrEmpy` with a boolean result and not string, it works fine. so i was wondering the `IF ELSE` and `IIF` affects the validation.