# Setting ASP.net MVC model class int, string & DateTime value to dbnull

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dbnull

Hey all I am trying to assign a **DBNull** to an int class value as shown below:

```
namespace ETTData.Models
{
    public class CHeld
    {
        public class AdNo {
            public int RequestID { get; set; } = DBNull.Value;

            public string TLead { get; set; } = DBNull.Value;

            public DateTime RequestDate { get; set; } = DBNull.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

However, I get the error(s) of:

> Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DBNull' to 'int' ETTData
>
> Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DBNull' to 'string'  ETTData
>
> Error CS0037  Cannot convert null to 'DateTime' because it is a non-nullable value type

This also seems to be an issue when doing a **DateTime** and **string** varibles?

What would I be missing in order to get this to work?

Comment: Why are you trying to assign a *database specific* type to your C# objects? Why is `null` not an option here?

Comment: @DigiFriend I've read that **NULL** and **DBNull** are different from each other and if you are using varibles that are to be saved in a database then you need to use **DBNull** and not **NULL**. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958379/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-system-dbnull-value

Comment: Yes, but *only* when you are saving to the DB. You can't assign `DBNull` to C# objects, as you have seen.

Comment: What if there is no value, say for RequestID, and therefore it never sets it to anything if i dont have **= something** in the variable definition?

Comment: I'd keep the C# properties as null. Then default the parameters to null in your DB procs that can be null and omit them from the SQL command parameter list if they equal null.

Comment: Well, try it and see if it works, cuz this approach isn't working at the moment. Are you using an ORM?

Answer (score 1):

Hi why are you trying to put db null value to your model class?

if you wan't your properties to receive null values you can use `?` to make your types to nullable.

```
 public int? RequestID { get; set; }
 public string TLead { get; set; }
 public DateTime? RequestDate { get; set; }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Quick, remove the ? on string!

Comment: There is no `string?` as `string` is always nullable

Comment: Yup Eagle Eyes :-D. Thanks!

Comment: @Mats391 yup your right. there is no ? for string types bcoz it is always nullable..

Answer (score 1):

You can only use `DBNull` with types that accept it as a valid value - the built in types do not - nor does any type you can create yourself - class/struct cannot be derived from `DBNull` - it is sealed, so can't be inherited from.

You need to use `null` for properties that can be nullable in the DB (and model struct types that cannot be null, such as `int` as nullables - `int?`).

When saving to the DB, check if these are `null` and if so, pass in `DBNull` to your database.