# How to Pass Dynamic Parameter

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have two Parameter in Sql Function (StartDate and EndDate).I am passing the input Parameter from C# Code.When I Pass two Parameter,the Query result working fine.My question is, How to Pass only "EndDate" no "Start Date" (Start Date is Empty),So the Query result should be all record till "EndDate"

Sql Query:

```
Select * from FnEmployeeProduction(?,?)
```

Comment: I think you may need to pass **`null`** and need to do appropriate validation in your `UDF`.

Comment: You may need to send the dbnull if you dont have a proper value

Comment: It depends on how you are processing the dates in your function. You could declare the parameters as default NULL, or declare default values (e.g. '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000')... or a combination of both?

Comment: `Select * from FnEmployeeProduction(somevalue, null)`and handle the possiblity for null in the funtion

Answer (score 1):

you need to send NULL to the database, but for some reason microsoft has invented `DBNull.Value`in c#

Here is an example of calling your function in c#

```
DateTime? beginDate = null;
DateTime? endDate = DateTime.now;

using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * from FnEmployeeProduction (@begin, @end)");
{  
    command.Parameters.Add("@begin", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = (beginDate == null) ? (object)DBNull.Value : beginDate;
    command.Parameters.Add("@end", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = (endDate == null) ? (object)DBNull.Value : endDate;

    // now you can use this command object to send to your DB
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(your conn string))
    {  
       connection.Open();
       command.Connection = connection;
       using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
       {
           adapter.Fill(your datatable);
       }
    }
}
```

And inside your function you need to handle null values off course

```
create function FnEmpoyeeProduction (@begin datetime, @end datetime) as
begin
     if @begin is not null 
     begin
     end
     and so on...
end
```

Comment: This is the "idiot reason": There's a big conceptual difference between `DbNull.Value` and `null`. The keyword `null` represents an invalid reference. The class `System.DbNull` represents a nonexistent value in a database field.

Comment: @GuidoG 'idiotic reason'? First read about the difference here, then you can correct your statement: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958379/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-system-dbnull-value

Comment: @WoIIe I know the difference, but there still is no reason to create a DBNull.Value in c# the compiler could easily know the difference from the code

Comment: @L-Four From the other anwser in your link its clear I am not the only one that thinks DBNull.Value is annoying. But ok I removed the idiot word in my answer there is no need for discussions about this