# Parameter missing at ExecuteNonQuery with stored procedure in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: stored-procedures, ado.net

Below is my code and I get an error at `ExecuteNonQuery`:

> @Name parameter missing.

I have tried many time and even no error during building of program. The stored procedure contains an insert statement with 4 parameters, 3 of `varchar` type and one `integer` type as the primary key.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace CompanyMaster
{
    public class Master
    {
         public IEnumerable<Company> Companies
         {
            get
            {
                string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;

                List<Company> companies = new List<Company>();

                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetAllCompany", con);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    con.Open();

                    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        Company company = new Company();
                        company.CompanyCode = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["CompanyCode"]);
                        company.CompanyName = rdr["CompanyName"].ToString();
                        company.CompanyAddress = rdr["CompanyAddress"].ToString();
                        company.CompanyMail = rdr["CompanyMail"].ToString();

                        companies.Add(company);
                    }
                }
                return companies;
            }
       }

       public void Addcompany(Company company)
       {    
           string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;

           using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
           {
               SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spAddCompany", con);
               cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

               cmd.Parameters.Clear();

               SqlParameter paramCode = new SqlParameter();
               paramCode.ParameterName = "@Code";
               paramCode.Value = company.CompanyCode;
               cmd.Parameters.Add(paramCode);

               SqlParameter PName = new SqlParameter("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
               //PName.ParameterName = "@Name";
               PName.Value = company.CompanyName;
               cmd.Parameters.Add(PName);

               SqlParameter paramAddress = new SqlParameter();
               paramAddress.ParameterName = "@Address";
               paramAddress.Value = company.CompanyAddress;
               cmd.Parameters.Add(paramAddress);

               SqlParameter paramMail = new SqlParameter();
               paramMail.ParameterName = "@Mail";
               paramMail.Value = company.CompanyMail;
               cmd.Parameters.Add(paramMail);

               con.Open();
               cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();-- error is occurring here
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Here is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spAddCompany
    @Code INT,
    @Name NVARCHAR(50),
    @Address NVARCHAR(60),
    @Mail NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO CompanyMaster (CompanyCode, CompanyName, CompanyAddress, CompanyMail)
    VALUES (@Code, @Name, @Address, @Mail)
END
```

`@Name` parameter is missing when the code reaches `ExecuteNonQuery`.

Comment: Side note: The type of the `@Name` parameter in the stored procedure is `NVARCHAR`, but in your C# code it is `SqlDbType.VarChar`. You should change it to `SqlDbType.NVarChar`. You should use the same style for all the other parameters as well.

Comment: does't working..thanks

Comment: That was a side note, not a solution.

Comment: @RacilHilan ok..

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem has to do with `null` vs `DBNull.Value`.
Check if `company.CompanyName` is null (in c#). If it is, you should pass `DBNull.Value` instead.
For more information on the difference between the two, read [What is the difference between null and System.DBNull.Value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958379/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-system-dbnull-value)

From [Configuring Parameters and Parameter Data Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/configuring-parameters-and-parameter-data-types):

> **Note**
>
> When you send a null parameter value to the server, you must specify [**`DBNull`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dbnull?view=netframework-4.7.2), not `null` (`Nothing` in Visual Basic). The `null` value in the system is an empty object that has no value. [**`DBNull`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dbnull?view=netframework-4.7.2) is used to represent null values. For more information about database nulls, see [Handling Null Values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/handling-null-values).

Also, You can add parameters to the command and set their values in a single line of code, like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = company.CompanyName;
```

This will make your code much shorter and more readable.

Here are the changes I've made to your code that I think should solve your problem:

```
public void Addcompany(Company company)
{    
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;

    using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        // SqlCommand also implements the IDisposable interface
        using(var cmd = new SqlCommand("spAddCompany", con))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Code",  SqlDbType.Int).Value = company.CompanyCode;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = company.CompanyName as object ?? (object)DBNull.Value;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Address", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = company.CompanyAddress as object ?? (object)DBNull.Value;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Mail", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = company.CompanyMail as object ?? (object)DBNull.Value;
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Note the use of the null coalescing operator (`??`) and the casting to `object`.