# Save distinct values in a column conditionally to a list

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following which has worked for me so far, however I now want to only select locations if another column (Location ID) is not null. How do I add this filter to my list?

Location and Location ID are both columns in datatable dt.

EDIT: edited code to try to match what was in the comments. I also tried != "" and the list isn't populated either way.

Last edit: The below code didn't work because I had dt as var originally. Removing the var and just declaring the datatable fixed it and it now works correctly.

```
var distinctLocs = dt.AsEnumerable()
               .Where(s => s.Field<string>("Location ID") != null)
               .Select(s => new
               {
                   id = s.Field<string>("Location"),
               })
               .Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: `dt.AsEnumerable().Where(s => s.Location_ID != null).Select(...).....`

Comment: Is Location_ID a foreign key, and is Location a string field or an associated table?

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with your code. But then, we have no [mcve] to check.

Comment: You've tried running this, I assume? What happens?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between null and System.DBNull.Value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958379/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-system-dbnull-value)