# System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.Byte[]'.'

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, icsharpcode

My operation work is when I click on the cells of `gridview`: The Records in `gridview` will go to the `textbox` and picture box.

This exception error occurs when I click on an empty cell(No records in datagridview) in the gridview.

[I share picture of my operation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ho35.png)

[It comes from the error is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7QIu.png).
Here is my codes:

```
  private void btn_picopen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /*OpenFileDialog opf = new OpenFileDialog();
        opf.Filter = "Select Pic(*.JPG;*.png;.gif)|*.jpg;*.png;*.gif";
        if (opf.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
         {
            pic_staff.Image = Image.FromFile(opf.FileName);
        }*/
        OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        dialog.Filter = "png files(*.png)|*.png|jpg files(*.jpg)|*.jpg|All files(*.*)|*.* ";
        if(dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            imglocation = dialog.FileName.ToString();
            pic_staff.ImageLocation = imglocation;
        }
        


    }
private void btn_save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (Isvalid())
        {
            byte[] images = null;
            FileStream streem = new FileStream(imglocation, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            BinaryReader brs = new BinaryReader(streem);
            images= brs.ReadBytes((int)streem.Length);

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Add_New_Staff VALUES(@Staff_Name, @Father_Name, @City, @Address, @Mobile_No, @E_mail, @CNIC, @Education, @Subject, @Experience, @pic, @designation)", con);  //AddEsp ki jaga store procedure ka name
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Staff_Name", txt_name.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Father_Name", txt_fathername.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", txt_city.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", txt_address.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobile_No", txt_mobileno.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@E_mail", txt_email.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CNIC", txt_cnic.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Education", txt_education.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Subject", txt_subject.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Experience", txt_experience.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@designation", txt_designation.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pic", images);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Staff_Id", this.staff_Id);


            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("New Staff has been Added", "Saved", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            GetStudentsrecord();
            Clearformat();
        }
    }
 private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

        staff_Id = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value);
        txt_name.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        txt_fathername.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        txt_city.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        txt_address.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        txt_mobileno.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
        txt_email.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
        txt_cnic.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[7].Value.ToString();
        txt_education.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[8].Value.ToString();
        txt_experience.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[9].Value.ToString();
        txt_subject.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[10].Value.ToString();
        txt_designation.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[11].Value.ToString();
        // pic_staff.Image = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[10].Value as Image;
        byte[] bytes = (byte[])dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[12].Value;
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
        pic_staff.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);


    }
```

Comment: Also see [What is the difference between null and System.DBNull.Value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958379/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-system-dbnull-value)

Comment: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) [AddWithValue is Evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: I m beginner in c#. I don't Much know about C# codes.So guide me with the best and easy way.

Comment: @gmj There are already links to potential answers in the comments. Have you read them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to detect only one row's data, you can use `datagirdview.CurrentRow` property.

You can use `Convert.IsDBNull` method to check if the value is `DBnull`.

Here is code example may help you.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((!Convert.IsDBNull(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value)))
            {
                byte[] bytes = (byte[])dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value;
                Image image = byteArrayToImage(bytes);
                pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                pictureBox1.Image = image;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("there is no image in the row, please click aonther row");
            }
        }

       
        //convert bytearray to image
        public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
        {
            using (MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn))
            {
                return Image.FromStream(mStream);
            }
        }
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can check the first column before performing all of those code by

```
if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value != null)
{
    staff_Id = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value);
    ......
}
```

or you can just uncheck your grid's Enable Adding property to eliminate that new empty row.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qd1Lv.png)