# C# Where clause won't return the null values from a nullable bool

Tags: c#, linq, nullable-reference-types

I have a nullable bool which contains true / false / null on a SQL server database.  I am trying to query the server to return a dataset which contains false `FlagForDelete` records and another to return null `FlagForDelete` records.  I've tried several things and cannot isolate the two data sets I need for my target condition.

Can someone provide a hint on how I can accomplish this?  Thanks very much.

Target condition

```
Dataset1 to contain only false records.  
Dataset2 to contain only null records.
```

I've tried the below code and can't get it to work.  I get all records regardless of true/false/null.

Dataset

```
MaterialID  |   StockQty    |   FlagForDelete
----------------------------------------------
MAT1        |   10          |   true
MAT2        |   20          |   false
MAT3        |   30          |   null
```

Model

```
public class Material
{
    public int MaterialID { get; set; } 
    public decimal? StockQty { get; set; }      
    public bool? FlagForDelete { get; set; }     
}
```

Controller

```
IQueryable<Material> Dataset1 = _context.Material.AsNoTracking().Where(ffd => ffd.FlagForDelete == false);
IQueryable<Material> Dataset2 = _context.Material.AsNoTracking().Where(ffd => ffd.FlagForDelete == null);
```

Comment: Use this to check the DB field for NULL, `ffd.FlagForDelete == DBNull.Value` ... [DBNull.Value vs. null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958379/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-system-dbnull-value)

Comment: `I've tried the below code and can't get it to work. I get all records regardless of true/false/null.` So _both_ of your `controller` lines of code return all records?

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: @quaabaam That will not even compile as you cannot compare a `bool?` to a `DBNull`.  You'd use `DBNull` when dealing with ADO.Net, not with Linq.

Comment: @juharr, doh! Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```csharp
Reproduced this with SQL server.
Added your Material class. Correction to you keys were made.
The HasValue as stated was fine. Also Convert.ToBoolean helped with translation. 
Some options for various results have been provided.
 

       [HttpGet]  
       public IActionResult GetNulls()
       {
           List<Material> mats = new List<Material>
           {
               new Material { MaterialID = 1, StockQty = 10, FlagForDelete = true },
               new Material { MaterialID = 2, StockQty = 20, FlagForDelete = false },
               new Material { MaterialID = 3, StockQty = 30 }
           };
           string Response = "SUCCESS:";
           try
           {
               List<Material> NotFalse = mats.Where(m => m.FlagForDelete != Convert.ToBoolean(false)).ToList();
               List<Material> NotTrue = mats.Where(m => m.FlagForDelete != Convert.ToBoolean(true)).ToList();
               List<Material> NotEither = mats.Where(m => m.FlagForDelete != Convert.ToBoolean(true) &&  m.FlagForDelete != Convert.ToBoolean(false)).ToList();
               List<Material> Lakemann = mats.Where(m => !m.FlagForDelete.HasValue).ToList();
               var combine = new { NotFalse, NotTrue, NotEither , Lakemann };
               var options = new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true };
               string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(combine, options);
               return Ok(json);
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {Response = "ERROR: **" + ex.Message;}
           finally
           {};
           return NoContent();
       }

JSON
{
  "NotFalse": [
    {
      "MaterialID": 1,
      "StockQty": 10,
      "FlagForDelete": true
    },
    {
      "MaterialID": 3,
      "StockQty": 30,
      "FlagForDelete": null
    }
  ],
  "NotTrue": [
    {
      "MaterialID": 2,
      "StockQty": 20,
      "FlagForDelete": false
    },
    {
      "MaterialID": 3,
      "StockQty": 30,
      "FlagForDelete": null
    }
  ],
  "NotEither": [
    {
      "MaterialID": 3,
      "StockQty": 30,
      "FlagForDelete": null
    }
  ],
  "Lakemann": [
    {
      "MaterialID": 3,
      "StockQty": 30,
      "FlagForDelete": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: The conversion to bool is very helpful with those using SQL back ends.  The HasVAlue is perfect for those looking for only null.  Thank you @Rooster Man.

Answer (score -1):

In C# a boolean column that can been null would map to a `bool?`;

```cs
...Where(ffd => ffd.FlagForDelete == false);
...Where(ffd => !ffd.FlagForDelete.HasValue);
```