# .NET Core: IEnumerable parameters are not supported, pass an array or List instead

Tags: postgresql, .net-core

I am trying to save JSON into my Postgres database from .NET Core.

This is my table :

[image]

This is my query:

```
string strCommandInsert = @"INSERT INTO  public.""City"" (""id"", ""externalId"", ""tags"", ""members"", ""geometry"") values (@id, @externalId, @tags, @members, @geometry);";

await using (var command = new NpgsqlCommand(strCommandInsert, conn))
{
    foreach (var customer in cities.elements)
    {
        var tags = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customer.tags);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", customer.id);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@externalId", Guid.NewGuid());
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tags", JObject.Parse(tags));

        int nRows = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync(String.Format("Number of rows inserted={0}", nRows));
    }
}
```

But I get this error:

> Opening connection
>
> Unhandled exception. System.NotSupportedException: IEnumerable parameters are not supported, pass an array or List instead
>
> at Npgsql.Internal.TypeMapping.TypeMapper.g__ResolveLong|30_0(Type type)
> at Npgsql.Internal.TypeMapping.TypeMapper.ResolveByClrType(Type type)
> at Npgsql.Internal.TypeMapping.TypeMapper.g__ResolveLong|30_0(Type type)
> at Npgsql.Internal.TypeMapping.TypeMapper.ResolveByClrType(Type type)
> at Npgsql.Internal.TypeMapping.TypeMapper.g__ResolveLong|29_0(Object value, Type type)
> at Npgsql.Internal.TypeMapping.TypeMapper.ResolveByValue(Object value)
> at Npgsql.NpgsqlParameter.g__Resolve|96_0(TypeMapper typeMapper)
> at Npgsql.NpgsqlParameter.ResolveHandler(TypeMapper typeMapper)
> at Npgsql.NpgsqlParameter.Bind(TypeMapper typeMapper)
> at Npgsql.NpgsqlParameterCollection.ProcessParameters(TypeMapper typeMapper, Boolean validateValues, CommandType commandType)
> at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
> at EazyCityCA.Startup.Main(String[] args) in /Users/alt/Projects/MyProjects/eazy_city/EazyCityCore/EazyCityCA/Program.cs:line 104
> at EazyCityCA.Startup.Main(String[] args) in /Users/alt/Projects/MyProjects/eazy_city/EazyCityCore/EazyCityCA/Program.cs:line 107
> at EazyCityCA.Startup.Main(String[] args) in /Users/alt/Projects/MyProjects/eazy_city/EazyCityCore/EazyCityCA/Program.cs:line 109
> at EazyCityCA.Startup.(String[] args)

This tags json:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass a value through npgsql to a JSON column then you pass that value as a string, see https://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/basic.html?q=json

The error message is somewhat confusing as it just happens that `JObject` implements `IEnumerable` and most often the coding error is that someone wanted to pass multiple values, so an array or list type should have been passed, but in your case you want to use the string instead.

Npgsql has built-in support for `System.Text.Json` but requires a plugin for support for Newtonsoft's `Json.net` https://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/jsonnet.html?tabs=datasource which would allow you to use the JObject directly, but since you already have the string and are parsing it that seems a bit redundant.

Comment: If I want to save null value what I have to do ? I added `AddWithValue("@members", null);` but I got error ` Parameter '@members' must have either its NpgsqlDbType or its DataTypeName or its Value set
`

Comment: @CyrustheGreat use DbNull.Value instead of C# null https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958379/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-system-dbnull-value

Comment: I removed `JObject.Parse(tags)`and I added `AddWithValue("@tags", tags)`but I got error `column "tags" is of type json but expression is of type text`?

Comment: @CyrustheGreat IIRC you need to use a cast in your SQL when passing the string, so `@tag :json`

Comment: See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/datatype-json.html#JSON-KEYS-ELEMENTS 
Casting a string to json is a postgresql thing not a dot not one

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it to string, which provvides valid JSON

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tags", JObject.Parse(tags).ToString());
```

Comment: yes, but `tags` is JSON string

Comment: that doesn't matter postgres will convert it automatically as long as it is valid jason, and this is what the tostring produces, did you try it