# What Is DBNull Needed For Anyway?

Tags: c#, dbnull

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the point of DBNull?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488727/what-is-the-point-of-dbnull)

Since the beginning of my adventure with .NET I have always asked myself one question:

**why do we need the DBNull type? Is a simple null reference not enough?**

MSDN says that DBNull "Represents a nonexistent value". From a logical point of view - this one sentence explains why a null reference cannot be used - because it is a null reference and not a lack of value. But is it enough to introduce a type that causes a lot of trouble?

BTW: If anyone has something to say in defense of the `DBNull` I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I think it causes troubls for you, not to me. :-P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[DBNull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) has existed since the earliest versions of .Net framework.

Nullable value types ([`Nullable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)) has only existed since version 2 of the framework.

Since, before version 2, it was possible to receive, say, a null int value back from the database, how would you propose it be represented? Then, for consistency, the same was used to represent all DB nulls, whether they translated to a value or reference type.

Answer (score 2):

`DBNull.Value` represents 'NULL' in the database; it is not the same as 'null'.

Answer (score 1):

We need it so we can detect if a value returned from a database is null or not.
Typically, [`Convert.IsDBNull`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.isdbnull.aspx) is used to perform the check.

The `DBNull` type is not the same as the programming value `null`

Answer (score 0):

null in c# is something different than NULL in the SQL context, the SQL NULL in C# is exposed not as string but as `DbNull.Value` which makes sense, if it was not like that how would you check for db null? comparing a string `"NULL"` would not have been the same...