# DBNull.Value as optional parameter

Tags: c#, null, option-type

Is is possible to pass DBNull.Value as optional parameter?
I tried in C#

```
private void CallSP(string param0, string param2 = DBNull.Value)
{
}
```

Its is giving error. I need to call a Stored procedure in this method, so i am passing DBNull.Value. 
Is'DBNull.Value' and 'null' are treated as same in SQL Server? Shall i pass 'null' instead of 'DBNull.Value'???

Comment: @1ntello "never use null" is contrary - there's absolutely no reason not to use `null`, and it isn't not *very* different to the null in SQL - only null-equality is different, and that is trivial to make consistent.

Comment: perhaps also see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9632050/23354

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`DBNull.Value` is **not** a string, and is **not** a constant (optional parameter values must be constants). The way to do this is to default it to regular `null`, and handle the `null` when adding the parameter:

```
private void CallSP(string param0, string param2 = null)
{
    ...
    object value = (object)param2 ?? DBNull.Value;
    // ^^^ use value in the parameter
    ...
}
```

Comment: +1, just to state explicitly for OP, as it frequently trips people up - setting a parameter value to null will result in that parameter not being passed and you'd end up with a SqlException. null != DBNull.Value

Comment: @AdaTheDev personally, I have yet to find a **compelling** reason for the **existence** of `DBNull`. I've seen many arguments - none of them very compelling.

Comment: @MarcGravell - couldn't agree more

Comment: @MarcGravell That's OK. Personally I can never see any compelling reasons to make varchar fields nullable. But someone somewhere out there may think things like that are useful!

Comment: @AdaTheDev you might find this interesting then: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9632050/23354