# Inserting NULL to SQL DB from C# DbCommand

Tags: c#, sql, dbcommand

```
        DbParameter param = comm.CreateParameter();
        param = comm.CreateParameter();
        param.ParameterName = "@StaffId";
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(activity.StaffId))
            param.Value = activity.StaffId;
        param.DbType = DbType.String;
        comm.Parameters.Add(param);
```

The above does not work (obviously), object not instantiated. I am attempting to insert a NULL into the database when StaffId is NOT populated. How can I achieve this?

Comment: you can use DBNull.Value

Comment: Perfect! If you post this as answer I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: As for why... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488727/what-is-the-point-of-dbnull/9632050#9632050

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can use DBNull.Value when you need to pass NULL as a parameter to the stored procedure.

```
param.Value = DBNull.Value;
```

Or you can use that instead of your `if` operator:

```
param.Value = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(activity.StaffId) ? activity.StaffId : (object)DBNull.Value;
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit Andrey - appreciate it. It seems crazy to have to cast this as an object though (to me anyway).

Answer (score 8):

Try `DBNull.Value`

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(activity.StaffId))
   param.Value = activity.StaffId;
else
  param.Value=DBNull.Value;
```

Comment: is there a way of using the ? operator for a sort of shorthand if else statement here?? It seems to not like the String/DBNull.Value conversion!?

Comment: Try this: param.Value = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(activity.StaffId) ? activity.StaffId : (object)DBNull.Value;

Answer (score 4):

You can always use the null-coalescing operator (??)

```
param.Value = activity.StaffId ?? (object)DBNull.Value;
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `DBNull.Value`:

```
param.Value = DBNull.Value;
```