# Insert a null value into an int column in SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
public bool insertRowIntoApplicant(int AnsId, string Name)
{
    string CS = Utilities.GetConnString();

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert Into ApplicantTable (AnswerableId, Name) values (@AnsId, @Name);

        SqlParameter paraAnsId = new SqlParameter()
                    {
                        ParameterName ="@AnsId",
                        SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int,
                        Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input,
                        Value = AnsId
                    };
        cmd.Parameters.Add(paraAnsId);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(paraName);
    }
}
```

I get the value from a hidden field

```
int getAnswerabelValue = Convert.ToInt32(hfAnswerableID.Value);

if (dal_Obj1.insertRowIntoApplicant(getAnswerabelValue, Name)
{
}
```

My question is that `getAnswerabelValue` sometimes can be null, so how to change my code?

Comment: Does the database column accept `null`? Have you tried using `int? AnsId`? What is the type of `hfAnswerableID.Value`?

Comment: you want a nullable int then... declare as int? getAnswerableValue

Comment: Do you mean that `hfAnswerableID` can sometimes be null?  Because in this code `getAnswerabelValue` most certainly can not be null.  What is `hfAnswerableID`?  Where does it come from?

Comment: Yes the column accept null value

Comment: Yes hfAnswerableID can be be null sometimes

Comment: @jawed: If, in your method, `AnsId` needs to allow for null values then make its type `int?` (shorthand for `Nullable<int>`) in the method signature.  Then you can pass it a nullable integer.

Comment: Maybe not quite a duplicate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9801649/inserting-null-to-sql-db-from-c-sharp-dbcommand) but see how to use `DBNull.Value` also. Though I agree, in this case it’s simpler to just use `int?`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The column can be null? Then the variable should be `Nullable<int>` too.

```
int? ansIdOrNull = null;
int ansId;
if(int.TryParse(hfAnswerableID.Value, out ansId))
    ansIdOrNull = ansId;

// pass ansIdOrNull to the method...
```

---

You have to use `DBNull.Value` in case it is `null`:

```
public bool insertRowIntoApplicant(int? ansId, string Name)
{
    string CS = Utilities.GetConnString();
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert Into ApplicantTable(AnswerableId,Name) values(@AnsId,@Name);
       SqlParameter paraAnsId = new SqlParameter()
        {
            ParameterName ="@AnsId",
            SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int,
            Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input,
            Value = (object)ansId ?? DBNull.Value
        };
        // initialize paraName
        cmd.Parameters.Add(paraAnsId);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(paraName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why should go extra parsing while you can actually use string to post it into the SQL table? Like `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue('@getAnswerabelValue', string.IsNullOrEmpty(getAnswerabelValue) ? DBNull.Value : getAnswerabelValue)`

Comment: Because you want type safety, you want to control what the database stores and because you want to store null values. The method should not need to take the value somewhere but it should get it as parameter. The only valid type is an int?

Answer (score 0):

If your db column accepts nulls then you will want to declare your int as a nullable int

```
int? getAnswerabelValue = hfAnswerableID;
```

Comment: If `hfAnswerableID` is already an `int?` then you'd also want to drop the `.Value`, and at that point there's no need for `getAnswerabelValue` in the first place.