# C#: how to cast a database field of guid type holding a null value to a local variable?

Tags: c#, ms-access, guid

I have on one side an Access database, where `Tbl_Application.id_connexion` is a field with a `Guid` type (called 'replication ID' in ms Access terminology).

I am collecting some data from this Tbl_Application table through a `DataRow[]` array, `dr_Tbl_Application`. The following code reads the first DataRow:

```
private Guid? mid_connexion = null;
mid_connexion = (Guid)dr_Tbl_Application[0]["id_connexion"]
```

Everything is ok as long as `Tbl_Application.id_connexion` holds a value. In case this field does not hold a value, I will get the following error:

```
InvalidCastException was unhandled
```

And these are some things I can see in the immediate window:

```
? dr_Programme[0]["id_Connexion"]
{}

? dr_Programme[0]["id_Connexion"].GetType()
{Name = "DBNull" FullName = "System.DBNull"}

? dr_Programme[0]["id_Connexion"] is System.DBNull
true
```

So, to avoid my exception, I guess I'd better test before transfering a unique identifier value from a field in a database to a local variable. This said, I am still bothered by my finding, and I'd like to dig deeper into this issue.

My questions are the following:

1. Is there a way to write some basic code to assign a value from a database Guid value to a local Guid object without having to test on `System.DBNull`?
2. Why should the same instruction, applied on the same object, return different types, depending if the the original fields holds or not a value?

Edit on question 2:

```
? dr_Programme[0]["id_Connexion"].GetType()
```

returns System.Guid type when the corresponding field is populated in the original table, while

```
? dr_Programme[0]["id_Connexion"].GetType()
```

returns System.DBNull type when the field is null (or not populated) in the original table ...

Comment: have you tried `mid_connexion = (Guid?)dr_Tbl_Application[0]["id_connexion"]`note the ? to mark it as a nullable Guid like you did with your mid_connexion. Cos the `(Guid)dr_Tbl_Application[0]["id_connexion"]` will attempt to cast null to a type of GUID which is not a nullable type.

Comment: @Syneryx That doesn't work. System.DBNull can't be cast to Nullable<T>.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan my bad. but it seems Morten mertner has an answer.

Comment: This has already been discussed in a [similar question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/870697/unable-to-cast-object-of-type-system-dbnull-to-type-system-string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DBNull` implements the [*Null Object Design Pattern*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) to address [the difference between DB returning a NULL vs. not returning anything](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4488727/335858). Unfortunately, the lack of its intuitiveness keeps tripping up programmers for many years.

The best you can do is wrapping it in a generic method, like this:

```
public static T? GetNullable<T>(object obj) where T : struct
{
    if (obj == DBNull.Value) return null;
    return (T?)obj;
}
```

Now you can call this method like this:

```
mid_connexion = GetNullable<Guid>(dr_Tbl_Application[0]["id_connexion"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that you will have to keep checking for DBNull, unless you design your DB schema to not allow them to occur. Also note that DBNull is different from C# null.

You can probably make the code slightly less verbose by using the Convert class in C#. In general it will perform default conversions rather than throw an exception (e.g. when it encounters a null value; note that it does not to my knowledge know how to deal with DBNull values, so you'll need to deal with those manually).

My recommendation would be to create a set of extension methods to do the necessary work:

```
public static class AccessExtensions
{
    public static Guid GetGuidOrEmpty( this IDbReader reader, string columnName )
    {
        // all the code to check for DBNull and conversions goes here
        // ...

        return hasValue ? value : Guid.Empty;
    }
}
```

One last word of caution is that Access can be funny about GUIDs, such as requiring strings for insert/update but returning GUID types on select. This may have improved since I tried it in 2003 or thereabouts.

Comment: Guid management between Access tables and Access vba and\or other vb code has always been a real PITA ...

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
public static class SomeClass
    {
        public static Guid? With(this Guid? o, object x)
        {
            if (x is System.DBNull) return null;
            return o = (Guid)x;
        }
    }
```