# What is the best way to find out whether image column is null or not?

Tags: c#, sql-server, image, ado.net, dbnull

**Problem Definition:**
I have a table in a SQL Server database. This table has an column of type image and it allows null values. I'm going to read this table using `SqlDataReader` and show the images if they are available.

**What I tried first time:** To check whether the image column is null or not I did this

```
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();  // command is a SqlCommand

while(reader.Read())
{
    if(reader["Image"] != null)     // Image is a column name of the table
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

**The result:** But it never equals to null (I also checked the `Equal` method). This column never is null even if has not data inserted (In SQL Server I can see it is actually null)

**What I tried second time:** So I tried this code and its working but I wonder why it doesn't return null.

```
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();  // command is a SqlCommand

while(reader.Read())
{
    if(reader["Image"].GetType() != typeof(System.DBNull)) 
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

**Question:** Any idea to explain this behavior? I will be pleased if there is a better way to find out whether the columns of type Image in SQL Server Tables are null or not.

Comment: You should try to print out everything you can about the value when there is no image data - using an `else` in the second form. That should lead you to the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should just check for `DbNull` this way.

```
if(reader["Image"] != DbNull.Value)     // Image is a column name of the table
{
    //Do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain why it is different from the simple `null` value.

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad this question has a great answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488727/what-is-the-point-of-dbnull