# Override Exception class and Handle error without class referencing

Tags: c#, exception

I want to handle all errors at one place without referencing that class.

see my current structure.

```
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
{
    try
    {
        var a = 10;
        var b = 0;
        var c = a / b;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new LogEroor("", ex);
    }

    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    return View();
}
```

and my error handling class.

```
public class LogEroor : Exception
{
    public LogEroor(string message, Exception Ex) : base(message, Ex)
    {
        // error handling
    }
}
```

> My question

**Is there any way that I can call LogError method with Ex parameter when error occurs**, but I do not want to **call this method in each and every catch**, like I did over here.

Comment: How do you expect to call a method or even a constructor without specifiying it? What you want makes no sense at all, of course all your classes have to reference the generic exception-class if they´re up to *throw* one. Hpwever you could register to the [`AppDomain.UnhandledExceptionHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a typical [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The actual problem X you're trying to solve is, paraphrased:

> I want to log all exceptions that occur in my web application.

Your solution Y is, paraphrased:

> I will inherit from Exception, in which I will do the logging, and want any exception that is thrown to be converted to my exception type so it can be logged, without writing a try-catch block in all places where exceptions can occur.

Now you want help with problem Y, but that's the wrong approach altogether. You could do it using the [`AppDomain.UnhandledException` event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18984463/can-i-create-a-global-exception-handler-in-c-sharp-that-lets-the-code-continue-r), but you shouldn't.

Your solution is in [How do I log ALL exceptions globally for a C# MVC4 WebAPI app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15167927/how-do-i-log-all-exceptions-globally-for-a-c-sharp-mvc4-webapi-app): use exception filters.

Answer (score 1):

How do you expect to call a method or even a constructor without specifiying it? What you want makes no sense at all, of course all your classes have to reference the generic exception-class if they´re up to *throw* one.

You could register to the [`AppDomain.UnhandledExceptionHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception(v=vs.110).aspx) however which is a generic handler for all *not* handled exceptions. So instead of catching all your exceptions and throwing them again by *whrapping* them you can use this:

```
AppDomain.UnhandledExceptionHandler += (sender, args) => { throw new LogError(args.ExceptionObject); };
```

But this way you would throw an exception within the last layer of exception-handling your app has. This means you throw an exception which is never caught and will make your app crash. To avoid this implement your logging directly within that event.