# Why me program is closing after button click?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

In my developing PC, the application is working perfect. But when I make a installer and install the program in the client PC. Then whenever, I am clicking any button for doing something then the program is closing without giving any error.

Because there is no error on the code I have tried in the event log. and found that the

> Application error Event Id: 1000 level: 2 task: 100
>
> Forecast_v1.exe
>   1.0.0.0 5d397072 clr.dll
>   4.7.3416.0 5cabfc63 c00000fd 0000000000103c2a 5cc 01d542ca4230ccc8 C:\Program Files****\Forecast _v1.1\Forecast_v1.exe
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
>   e618747d-bcac-4c4f-aca3-cec16a0c2417

I have tried by updating the Entity framework, .Net framework, Office run-time 2010. Tried everything that I can imagine so far.

Can anyone tell what should I do. My targeted framework in the project configuration is .net Framework 4.6.1.

Comment: Did you miss to copy the actual message from the log?

Comment: Try set global exception handler. [Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18984584/4685428), [example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8148156/4685428). After this you should be able to log error

Comment: I found the problem is happening if the office version on the client PC is 64.
I tried on a PC where there is  office 32 bit installed and running perfect.