# How can I send a string as NULL to SQLServer using Dapper?

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper

I've got a scenario where a string in C# can be `null`. I need it to be `NULL` on SQLServer.

I'm sending it to SQLServer using Dapper with a query like:

```
connection.Query<MyObject>("[dbo].[sp_MyStoredProcedure]"), new
{
    StartDate: startDate
}, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

Where `startDate` is the string that can sometimes be equal to `null`.

The stored procedure's parameter is

```
@StartDate varchar(10) = NULL
```

When it's is `NULL` it returns all records. I've confirmed this behavior works via SSMS.

I read [this post](https://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/issues/detail?id=56) by Marc Gravell that states:

> The null vs DBNull issue is a constant cause of confusion; however, *generally* if people say `null` in C# they intend `null` in SQL. This is the approach that dapper adopts.

This leads me to believe that when the `string` is set to `null`, it should send `DBNull.Value` to SQLServer.

However, this doesn't appear to be the case. I get back 0 records from SQLServer when sending a `null` string. This seems indicative of sending an empty string, rather than a `DBNull.Value`.

Also, I can't send `DBNull.Value` directly:

```
connection.Query<MyObject>("[dbo].[sp_MyStoredProcedure]"), new
{
    StartDate: DBNull.Value
}, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

This produces an exception within Dapper:

> The member StartDate of type System.DBNull cannot be used as a parameter value

### Question

How can I send `NULL` to SQLServer, using Dapper, when I have a `string` in C# that can be `null`?

---

## Important

Dapper does indeed send `NULL` when a string is `null`. This assumption was a mistake on my part based on faulty information. Nonetheless, this question may serve to help someone else who makes an equally faulty assumption.

Furthermore, the accepted answer provides a good mechanism for dealing with optional or conditional parameters.

Comment: +1. It seems to me the question is quite valid for SO.

Comment: +1. Don't worry about the downvote, I guess somebody is having a bad Friday.

Comment: @crush, the links says `So I have to change my code to:

if (contact.IsActive.HasValue) p.Add("@isActive",contact.IsActive.Value); So I have to change my code to:

if (contact.IsActive.HasValue) p.Add("@isActive",contact.IsActive.Value);

So that it only adds the parameter if it has a value.` so you have to add only when it has value

Comment: I need to delete this question. I made an incorrect assumption based on faulty information provided to me by the dba who created the stored procedure. /sigh In fact, Dapper is sending `NULL`. It's the stored procedure's logic that is flawed. Sad that I can't rely on the dba, and had to wade through it myself to find the flaw.

Comment: Maybe I will leave the question in case someone else makes a faulty assumption like me.

Comment: @crush, this is a good question and I would ask you to leave it instead of deleting it, **This could be helpful for future visitors.** You can add your own answer indicating the mistake.

Comment: I'll edit the question to include a disclaimer about the mistake, and accept the quality answer below.

Comment: First of all, you cannot use `.ToString()` on a null. It's something I learned the hard way, as it concatenated my db and lists before.. Interesting. I would simply sanitize it before putting into a db. From what I understand, you want to read the `null` object and set it in the db as a `"NULL"` string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can choose not to send StartDate.

Example:

```
dynamic parameters = new {

};

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(startDate)) 
{
   parameters.StartDate = startDate;
}

connection.Query<MyObject>("[dbo].[sp_MyStoredProcedure]"), parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

Edit:

Also, your stored procedure must accept nulls. Here's an example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [ExampleProc]
   @StartDate datetime = null
AS
   Select @StartDate
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but my question is based on incorrect information. **Dapper does send `NULL` when `string` is null.** Nonetheless, this is a good approach to my problem, and I will probably use this anyways. Thanks for this answer!

Answer (score 13):

Yes, dapper knows to replace reference-`null` with `DBNull.Value` whenever it sees it. Because `DBNull` is my arch -nemesis, and if I never see it again in my application code (library code is different) I will die a little happier.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9632050/23354

Comment: Couldn't agree more, that's a great answer. Found it earlier. Thanks for the great work on Dapper. It's a godsend