# Why does DBNull.Value require a proper SqlDbType?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I've written a bunch of generic C# helper functions as a base for my SQL queries. All `null` object parameters are converted to a `DBNull.Value`. But when the target column is a `varbinary`, it tells me that `string` type is not compatible with the `binary` one and I must convert.

**Why do I need to `SqlDbType` a `DBNull.Value` in C#?** And is there any generic way to go around this?

```
// works for nvarchar but throws for varbinary columns
// notice the lack of SqlDbType as I don't know it for a null object
var param1 = new SqlParameter();
param1.Name = "@Param1";
param1.Value = DBNull.Value;
```

It's a null... it needs no type. SQL server knows the null's type. In SQL you say `[Column] IS NULL` not `[Column] IS TYPE NULL`. So null is untyped. And the target column is resolved from the query not the `SqlDbType`.

I just find this very unintuitive *(explicitly typing nulls)*. I'm wondering if I'm missing something...

Code is like this:

```
SqlCommand CreateCommand(string query, params object[] arguments) { ... }
// in here I walk the parameters and build the proper SqlParameter for them.
// this saves me from setting up the SqlParameters by hand.
```

**PS**: *String = NVarChar and Binary means VarBinary. Seriously...*
**PPS**: Not interested in EF or anything of the like.

Comment: Your question is not quite clear. How `string` to `binary` conversion related to `DBNull.Value`? Can you show some specific code sample?

Comment: Where did `string` enter the picture?  If it's `DBNull` it isn't `string`.  There's more to this story...

Comment: Also, can you show some example code that shows how you're doing this?  Might provide some useful context

Comment: Well, you can read [the point of `DBNull.Value`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488727/what-is-the-point-of-dbnull)

Comment: If you don't show your code we can't help to fix it.

Comment: Are you **not** setting `DBType` of your `param1` explicitly? It is not clear from your code.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev I'm not. That's the problem. A null object is of unknown type. But it's a null. So DBNull.Value should be clear enough for C# + SQL Client.

Comment: I believe the issue is that it needs to know the type of the parameter that is created.  It's defaulting to `varchar` and even though you set it's value to `null` it just sees that you are comparing incompatible types.  It's similar to creating a `string` variable in `C#` setting it to `null` and expecting to be able to compare it to a `int?`

Comment: @juharr This is not related to C#. That sqlparameter is just a means of delivering data to SQL server. But a NULL is always a NULL even in the database. **You say `[Column] IS NULL` not `[Column] IS VARBINARY(NULL)`.**

Comment: @CodeAngry I was trying to give you a parallel example in C#.  Your SQL will be `DECLARE @MyVar varchar` then `Set @MyVar = NULL` and then `[Column] = @MyVar`.  It's not going to translate into `IS NULL`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are not setting `DBType` of your `SqlParameter` explicitly - it has default value `SqlDBType.NVarchar` (see [MDSN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.dbtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for reference).

That's why you're getting exception - your parameter type is `NVarchar` but target column is `VarBinary`.

Note that you **have** to set `DBType` explicitly just because obviously ADO.NET can't deduce datatype from `DBNull.Value`.

`null` **is not a type** - it just **absense of value**, so if I'll give you `null` you can't deduce if it absence of `varchar` or, for example, absence of `int`.

**UPDATE**

I've made some experiments. Let's run simple code:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from sometable where somecolumn = @Param1");
cmd.Connection = _MyConnection;

var param = new SqlParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@Param1";
param.Value = DBNull.Value;
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

cmd.Connection.Open();
try
{
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
finally
{
    cmd.Connection.Close();
}
```

As we can see from SQL Profiler, this will be translated to actual SQL query as:

```
exec sp_executesql 
    N'select * from sometable where somecolumn = @Param1',
    N'@Param1 nvarchar(4000)',
    @Param1=NULL
```

So here we definitely will get exception if `somecolumn` datatype can't be implicitly converted from `varchar` just because `@Param1` datatype is explicitly set to `varchar`.

At the first look - this can be good enough explanation, right?

But there is one issue confusing me. If we will execute not a straight query, but "dummy" stored procedure having `varbinary` as parameter, let's say:

```
create procedure [dbo].[usp_Test]
(
    @Param1 varbinary(max)
)
as
begin
    set nocount on

    select null
end
```

Now let's try to call it like:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.usp_Test");
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
... and so on (the rest of code dealing with parameter)
```

Now in SQL Profiler we'll see just this:

```
exec dbo.usp_Test @Param1=NULL
```

And this is pretty strange since it is absolutely legal call without explicit specification of parameter type. Actually, if we call this in SQL Management Studio - we will not get any exception.

This part of ADO.NET behaviour is quite strange to me. Probably SQL Profiler doesn't shows complete process (despite the fact I turned on all events tracking), I don't know.

**Anyway - recommendation is still the same - always specify `DBType` of your `SqlParameter` explicitly.**

Comment: In SQL, `datatype` is quite irrelevant. It all depends on the target column. The type is stored in the table definition not in what I send over. This is not SQLite where any column can have any type.

Comment: But this isn't about what happens in SQL.  It's about what is happening in .NET quite apart from the underlying DBMS.

Comment: @roryap Still `DBNull.Value` is a special value. It should be clear it's a null and need no type as it's resolved based on the target column. This is what I find silly. Why type a lack of something? I was hoping I'm missing something and this is not by design.

Comment: @CodeAngry in fact, datatype is relevant in SQL. It looks "irrelevant" just because of implicit type conversions which are working good in most cases (for example, from `varchar` to `int` and so on) but not from `varchar` to `varbinary`

Comment: @AndyKorneyev You do understand we are talking about `DBNull.Value` not random valid objects? This is a very specific case... not `varchar` to `varbinary` conversion. Of course that's not gonna (supposed) to just work. But null is still null.

Comment: @CodeAngry, SQL is a strongly typed language so all parameters must have a data type regardless of the value (including DBNull.Value).  .NET must play by these rules when sending a parameter to the database even if it does it behind the scenes for you.  SQL Server will also implicitly convert parameters to a different data type according to data type precedence rules when needed.

Comment: Well... I like the edits. Indeed it's weird as they could have just not required a type for null values and make things easier when writing generic helpers.