# What is the use of DBNull in SSIS variables?

Tags: types, ssis

What is the point of the DBNull variable of an SSIS package? How can it be used? Can I assing a value to such a variable?

I've seen the [what-is-the-point-of-dbnull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488727/what-is-the-point-of-dbnull) question. Context of my question is much smaller - I would like to know only with SSIS in mind.