# why dataTable.Rows[0]["columnName"] == null. not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dbnull

I have a code like below

```
txtbox1.Text = dtDetails.Rows[0]["columnName"] == null ? "--": dtDetails.Rows[0]["columnName"].ToString().Trim();
```

above line is always `not null` even though `dtDetails.Rows[0]["columnName"] is null` whereas

```
txtbox1.Text = dtDetails.Rows[0]["columnName"] == DBNull.Value ? "--": dtDetails.Rows[0]["columnName"].ToString().Trim();
```

works perfectly. why is that? and how a `null` different over `DBNull.Value`

Comment: `DBNull.Value` is actually an [instance of a reference type](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/dbnull.cs#L28).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ADO.NET (`DataSet`, `DataTable`, and `DataRow`) represents SQL `NULL` values with `DBNull.Value` - this is to differentiate between runtime (C#/.NET) `null` from SQL `NULL`.

I strongly recommend reading this QA: [What is the point of DBNull?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488727/what-is-the-point-of-dbnull)

You can simplify your code, btw using `DataRowExtensions` - (add a reference to `System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll`)

```
txtbox1.Text = dtDetails.Rows[0]["columnName"] == DBNull.Value ? "--": dtDetails.Rows[0]["columnName"].ToString().Trim();
```

Can be changed to:

```
txtbox1.Text = dtDetails.Rows[0].Field<String>("columnName")?.Trim() ?? "--";
```

The `DataRowExtensions.Field<T>( this DataRow row, String name )` extension method checks for `DBNull.Value` and returns `null` - otherwise it returns the desired field without the overhead of looking-up the `DataRow` value twice as your code currently does.

#### Update for Visual Studio 2010

The OP says they're using Visual Studio 2010 (<sup>in 2019?!</sup>), so there are a few options:

1. [Upgrade to Visual Studio 2019](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/). Unlike the jump from VS2008 to VS2010, no 
   significant functionality has been removed from VS2010 that isn't still available in VS2019 - you can still target .NET Framework 2.0 and Windows XP in VS2019, for example.

   - The free ([as in beer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gratis_versus_libre)) Visual Studio 2019 Community is as-featured as VS2010 and is now free. You can also use the free and open-source [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) to work with Visual C# projects as well.
   - (VS2010 removed useful things from VS2008, like the Document Explorer, support for the .NET Compact Framework, the Object Test Bench feature, ran slower, and permanently changed how editor indentation worked (for the worse, imo))
2. If you have to use VS2010 (<sub>but why though?</sub>) you can hack your MSBuild project files to use a more modern C# compiler - but this is a complicated process - and there's no IDE editor support (so you'll get red-squiggly lines everywhere even though the project will build fine).

   - Visual Studio  2012 and later no-longer require one-way project and solution file upgrades when working with Visual Studio 2010 SP1 or later files - so you can use VS2019 with VS2010 files without anyone still using VS2010 complaining.
3. You could change the expression to perform `Trim()` *after* the `?? "--"` clause:

   ```
   txtbox1.Text = ( dtDetails.Rows[0].Field<String>("columnName") ?? "--" ).Trim();
   ```
4. You could use an extension method as a hacked-on conditional operator in a lambda:

   ```
   static class Extensions
   {
       public static TOut N<TIn,TOut>( this TIn value, Func<TIn,TOut> whenNotNull )
           where TIn : class
           where TOut : class
       {
           if( value == null ) return null;
           return whenNotNull( value );
       }
   }
   ```

   Used like so:

   ```
   txtbox1.Text = dtDetails.Rows[0].Field<String>("columnName").N( v => v.Trim() ) ?? "--";
   ```
5. Or extended further:

   ```
   static class Extensions
   {
       public static TOut N<TIn,TOut>( this TIn value, Func<TOut> whenNull, Func<TIn,TOut> whenNotNull )
           where TIn : class
           where TOut : class
       {
           if( value == null ) return whenNull();
           return whenNotNull( value );
       }
   }
   ```

   Used like so:

   ```
   txtbox1.Text = dtDetails.Rows[0].Field<String>("columnName").N( () => "--", v => v.Trim() );
   ```

Comment: Thanx for your Time and Your answer

Comment: `dtDetails.Rows[0].Field<String>("columnName")?.Trim() ?? "--";` why `?` after columnName actually it seems a compiler error

Comment: @HussainMd The `?.` is so that if the column value is returned as `null` then the `.Trim()` call won't cause a `NullReferenceException` (and the `??` will cause `"--"` to be returned). It was added in C# 6.0 in Visual Studio 2015, so it won't cause a compiler error unless you're using a very old IDE or compiler or your project settings are configured to use an older C# language version (check under Project Properties > Build > Advanced).

Comment: `@Dai`  **It was added in C# 6.0 in Visual Studio 2015, so it won't cause a compiler error unless you're using a very old IDE or compiler**   ohh damn I am using VS2010, what is the alternate way to handle if `.Trim()` throws `NullReferenceException` in VS2010 ?

Thanks

Comment: @HussainMd Well, ideally you should upgrade to Visual Studio 2019. Visual Studio is free now - why are you using VS2010? Anyway, you can use an extension method or reformulate the expression - I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check for the SQL `NULL` not the Net Framework `null`. They are two different Things